# Наследование абстрактного класса и многотабличное наследование  в Python

Tags: python, django

В чем отличие наследования от абстрактного класса и многотабличного наследования в Python, в частности в платформе Django? Хотелось бы уточнить, какая модель применима в том или ином случае, а так же ресурсоемкость каждого решения.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Принципиально эти два способа эквивалентны. Различия будут проявляться на уровне базы данных. При наследовании базового класса будет создана одна таблица наследующего класса, при этом нельзя создать экземпляр абстрактного класса. При использовании много табличного наследования, будет создано несколько таблиц, по одной для каждого класса, при этом сами таблицы будут связанны отношением внешнего ключа, в большинстве случаев эта связь будет один-к-одному.